# When a Messenger account is deleted by a member of a friend's family, can previous conversations with that person be deleted or altered as well?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-account

A dear friend passed away, and their sibling now has their phone. The sibling already publicly posted they are closing the Facebook / Messenger account on 11/01/2022. I want to be sure all my personal communication with my friend to date will not /cannot be damaged or removed.
Can the sibling go into my friend's account (before or after closing) and remove any comments, call attempts, etc. I have made to them, or they have made to me?
If so, what can I do to keep my records as they presently are? For legal purposes, I need to be sure my conversations/communications with my friend are secure and saved.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to download all your information to your computer.  You can then view any of it at your leisure.

Steps

- Log into Facebook Account
- Click **your photo** at top right
- Click on **Settings and Privacy**
- Click on **Settings**
- On left hand menu, click on **Privacy**
- Click on **Your Facebook Information**
- Click on **Download Profile Information**
- Select File type and dates
- Select the information
- Press **Request a download** button